# Docker - Kibana, APM, Elasticsearch issue -

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

This is my docker compose
https://pastebin.com/84sT5k9W

That's my output:

```
Starting kibana_elasticsearch_1 ... done

ERROR: for kibana  Container "032f18e00103" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

My docker ps

```
docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                           PORTS                    NAMES
32ca28fe3fbb        docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.0                 "/usr/local/bin/dumb…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes (unhealthy)         0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp   kibana_kibana_1
032f18e00103        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.0   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   5 minutes ago       Exited (78) About a minute ago                            kibana_elasticsearch_1
64a05e9aab13        playdingnow/delete-outdated-es-indexes:1.3            "sh /entrypoint.sh"      7 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                                              kibana_delete-indexes_1
                                      kibana_delete-indexes_1
```

Logs from unhealthy container

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-12-07T12:51:52,488Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.b.BootstrapChecks", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "032f18e00103", "message": "bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks" }
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-12-07T12:51:52,495Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "032f18e00103", "message": "stopping ..." }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-12-07T12:51:52,507Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "032f18e00103", "message": "stopped" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-12-07T12:51:52,507Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "032f18e00103", "message": "closing ..." }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-12-07T12:51:52,516Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "032f18e00103", "message": "closed" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2019-12-07T12:51:52,518Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.p.NativeController", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "032f18e00103", "message": "Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started" }
```

I don't really have a clue what has failed there

What I try to achieve is to have APM, Kibana and Elasticsearch in one docker compose

Comment: Can you share your docker-compose ? (at least the main parts like networking / environment variables)

Answer (score 7):

```
root@server1:/etc# sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you offer some explanation of what this is doing and why it solves the original question?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_maximum_map_count_check.html